# Why do we need the constraint in following optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

max $x^TAx$ s.t $||x||=1$ where A is a square symmetric matrix. The solution to this problem is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of A. According to me, we shouldn't need the constraint at all, we know that $Ax= \lambda x$ when $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, i.e. $x$ and $\lambda x$ are in the same direction, which means dot product is highest now when $\lambda$ is highest. This should hold irrespective of whether $||x||=1$ or not. What am I missing here?

Also, the solution to the minimization problem max $x^TAx$ s.t $||x||=1$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of A, which by the above logic shouldn't make sense because the dot product would be the smallest when either $\lambda$ is negative or when x is not an eigenvector

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and that $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $x^TAx=\lambda\|x\|^2$. If you put no restriction on $\|x\|$, then $\lambda\|x\|^2$ can take arbitrarily large values. But, if $\|x\|=1$, then $\lambda\|x\|^2=\lambda$.

Comment: What's the problem with arbitrarily large values? We have to find the eigenvector solution, which will remain the same nonetheless?

Comment: If we get arbitrarily large values, then there will not be a maximum, right?!